# Custom Cursor with Typecsript

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

My intention is to implement a custom cursor, which I got from here:

> https://codepen.io/designcourse/pen/GzJKOE

I've currently got it working on another project, which uses Javascript. My problem is that I've started working with Angular which uses Typescript and I don't know how to implement this cursor with Typescript. Any suggestions?

```
<div class="cursor"></div>
```

```
.cursor {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transition-duration: 200ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation: cursorAnim .5s infinite alternate;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.cursor::after {
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 8px solid gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: .5;
  top: -8px;
  left: -8px;
  animation: cursorAnim2 .5s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes cursorAnim {
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(.7);
  }
}

@keyframes cursorAnim2 {
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(.4);
  }
}

@keyframes cursorAnim3 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(3);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.expand {
  animation: cursorAnim3 .5s forwards;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```
        const cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');

        document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
            cursor.setAttribute("style", "top: "+(e.pageY - 10)+"px; left: "+(e.pageX - 10)+"px;")
        })

        document.addEventListener('click', () => {
            cursor.classList.add("expand");

            setTimeout(() => {
                cursor.classList.remove("expand");
            }, 500)
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First for listener to events use [`@HostListener`](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener)

1. **click event**

   use [`[ngClass]`](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngstyle-and-ngclass/) and bind the `expand` class as:`[ngClass]="{'expand':expand}"`
2. **Mouse move event**

   use [`[style.top]`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) and `[style.left]` and bind the value by `$event` of `mousemove`

[See working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-creating-custom-cursors?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

***TS:***

```js
    export class AppComponent  {
    
      top:any;
      left:any;
      expand=false;
    
      constructor() {}
    
    
      @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
      onClick($event) {
         this.expand=true;
         setTimeout(() => {
          this.expand=false;
         }, 500)
     }
    
    @HostListener('document:mousemove', ['$event'])
      onMousemove($event) {
        this.top=($event.pageY - 10)+ "px";
        this.left= ($event.pageX - 10)+ "px";
     }
    
    
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="cursor" [style.top]="top" [style.left]="left" [ngClass]="{'expand':expand}"></div>
```

**Use the same css as you post**

Comment: Thank you! Works so far. Do you know how to get an effect like this: [link] (http://momotaro.design/detail/kazuki.html)? When a link is being hovered the `expand` is being called and the cursor in the first place is different as well.

Comment: see here:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-creating-custom-cursors-378liv?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Thank you, that works. One more thing - do know who to change the normal cursor (just like in the link I mentioned above).

Comment: use `body,html{cursor:none}` in `style.css` file :https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-creating-custom-cursors-9l8knb?file=src/styles.css